# Does Tailwind CSS provide JavaScript by default?

Tags: javascript, css, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I'm using Tailwind CSS and Tailwind UI. I want to use the first navbar on [this page](https://tailwindui.com/components/application-ui/navigation/navbars). It says <kbd>Requires JS</kbd> above. Does Tailwind provide JavaScript by default? If so, which file do I import or use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<kbd>Requires JS</kbd> means you need to write your own JavaScript to handle the `open` and `closed` states of the menu when you click on the avatar.